# clio-api v2 Create Note Error

Tags: ruby, sinatra, clio-api

I am using Clio API v2 and I can't seem to get my ruby app within Sinatra to create a new note properly. This is the part in my app.rb that is giving me trouble:

```
note = client.notes.new(
  "subject" => "New note", 
  "regarding" => { "type" => "Matter", "id" => 1053548933 }
)

begin
  puts note.inspect
  puts note.save
rescue Exception => e
  puts 'Error!'
  puts e.message + "\n"
end
```

This works for creating a new matter and contact but I get this error with the Note call:

```
#<ClioClient::Note subject: "New Note", regarding_id: 1053548933> Error! 
Invalid Note Type
```

So it's getting the id and the subject but it seems like it isn't accepting the "type" => "Matter", and I can't figure out why for the life of me. The api is here [Clio v2 API](http://api-docs.clio.com/v2/index.html#create-a-note)

The confusing part of the api is in the top section it lists the "type" as an int, and then later in the same section lists it as a string?

I am hoping someone else has some experience with this and could show me how they got it working! Thanks all :)

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me, either... The API docs are inconsistent, and I don't see why your example fails (although I haven't actually tried it myself?)

Comment: What happens if you give an integer for the `type`?

Comment: Ints 0, 1, and 2 give the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Clio is in the process of shifting over to a new API V4 and preparing to deprecate API V2 in October 2018.  Can you implement your solution with API V4 ? https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation

Specifically a note can be created with the Clio API V4 using the following REST call:

POST https://app.clio.com/api/v4/notes?

with a JSON body provided:

JSON body

"data": {
"date": "2017-12-29",
"detail": "string",
"subject": "string",
"type": "Matter"
}

Date for the Note. (Expects an ISO-8601 date).

type is a string and can either be : 
"Matter" "Contact"